# Inteli J Emma Code Coverage

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I am writing unit tests using spock in a spring project. I am curious about the code coverage report. I run in Inteli J unit test with code coverage and get the tabke below. I don't get all the classes included within the project, but only the classes used in the unit tests.

How do I add a package and all class included in sub-packages recursively to the report?

[image]